# Using template class method outside class in dispatch table

Tags: c++, class, templates, dispatch-table

Im writing this small template class inheriting from an interface.
Inside my class I declared a variable I'd like to use outside and put it into a dispatch table. 
when I try to compile my program it throws me an error [image]

This is my source code:

```
template <typename T> class Operand;
typedef struct  s_typeInfo
{
    int     enum_nb;
    bool    (*fct_cast)(void);
}               t_typeInfo;


t_typeInfo typeInfo[] =
{
    {0, Operand::castInt8},
};

template <typename T>
class Operand : public IOperand {
    ...
    bool    castInt8(void) {...}
}
```

I have been trying to solve this problem in many different ways, but no one them work. How could I fix it? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: since `Operand` is a class template, you need `Operand<SomeTypeHere>::castInt8`

Comment: You also need to place the complete definition of `Operand` *before* the use of `Operand::castInt8`. In fact this is what your error message is telling you.

Comment: You also need to make castInt8 public and the fct_cast member in the typeinfo struct has to be a pointer to member function instead of a plain function pointer

Comment: @PaulinaSprawka Does IOperand has virtual `castInt8` method?

Comment: @bartop no, this is not a virtual method. Should it be virtual? If yes, why?

Comment: @PaulinaSprawka If it's inherited it is, in most cases, intended to be used polimorphically. But I do not know Your exact use case

Comment: @bartop yes, it's about polymorphism, but `castInt8` is not a member of `IOperand` class, it's `Operand`'s method

Answer (score 3):

There is number of things that cause erroer with compilation of Your code.

1. First of all, this construction `Operand::castInt8` makes no sense to compiler as `Operand` is not a class/struct but a class template. To get pointer to function You need a concrete type not a template of it. Therefore something like this would be more reasonable `Operand<int>::castInt8` for example.
2. The type of  `bool castInt8(void)` is not `bool (*)(void)` as it appears to be. Non-static member functions have more complicated types. In Your case it would be `bool (Operand<sometype>::*)(void)`.
3. One last thing - the compiler does not know `Operand` template has member `castInt8` before the definition. So You should reorder it like this:

   ```
   template <typename T>
   class Operand : public IOperand {
       ...
       bool    castInt8(void) {...}
   }

   t_typeInfo typeInfo[] =
   {
       {0, &Operand<sometype>::castInt8},
   };
   ```

Putting it all together it would look like this:

```
template <typename T> class Operand;

typedef struct  s_typeInfo
{
    int     enum_nb;
    bool    (Operand<int>::*fct_cast)(void);
}               t_typeInfo;


template <typename T>
class Operand {
    public:
    bool    castInt8(void) {}
};


t_typeInfo typeInfo[] =
{
    {0, &Operand<int>::castInt8},
};
```

Comment: Why did you put `int` in `Operand<int>::castInt8`?

Comment: @PaulinaSprawka I had to put something, it's just an example